# How to make admin grid row unclickable

Tags: grid

I have form grid with selectbox in grid. so i would like to make row unclickable because when i try to click on select box it trigger checkbox too.

[Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/AAsLG6kG8qdI)

any help would be very appreciate.

Comment: in which magento version?

Comment: magento version 1.8

Comment: you can try the answer given in grid.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i achieve this.

This is my grid constructor and code is as below.it will stop fire onrowclick event on selectbox click.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('customerGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true); // Using ajax grid is important
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultFilter(array('customer_ids'=>1)); // By default we have added a filter for the rows, that in_products value to be 1
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);  //Dont save paramters in session or else it creates problems
    $this->setAdditionalJavaScript("
    // added click on selectbox support
    serializerController.prototype.rowClick = serializerController.prototype.rowClick.wrap(function(o, grid, event) {
        var tagName = Event.element(event).tagName
            isSelect = (tagName == 'SELECT' || tagName == 'OPTION');
        if (!isSelect) {
            o(grid, event);
        }
    });
    ");
}
```

Comment: Solved for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code in grid.php for magento 1.x.x:

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will remove url or not remove click event

Comment: click event is coming because of the row url , so if you want to remove click event, you have to remove row url.

Comment: I did but nothing was changed :(

Comment: clear cache and try.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following method

```
getRowClickCallback
```

to my grid class (that overrides a core grid Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid), that returns some fake JS function, like this

```
public function getRowClickCallback()
{
    return 'fakeJsFunction';
}
```

And this can help you in achieving your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you will not pass "rowUrl" function in argument, In grid section Row URL will not be set.

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="adminhtml.promo.quote.grid.columnSet">
    <!--<arguments>
         <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="path" xsi:type="string">ezerus_shippingreport/*/*</item>
            <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
            </item>
        </argument> 
    </arguments>-->
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="entity_id">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>                        
</block>
```